# how to get full path of the current file including the src file in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file dateTesting.java . the path's directory is as follows: D:\workspace\Project1\src\dateTesting.java . I want the full path of this file as "D:\workspace\Project1\src" itself but when I use any of the following code, i get only "D:\workspace\Project1" . the src part is not coming.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File dir2 = new File(".");
System.out.println(dir2.getCanonicalPath().toString());
System.out.println(dir2.getAbsolutePath());
```

How can I get the full path as "D:\workspace\Project1\src" ? I'm using eclipse ide 3.5

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be other solutions

Comment: use
 File file = new File("com/yourpackage/dateTesting.java");
sysout(file.getAbsolouteFile());

Comment: I will be using a single file for different projects with different src file name....so i want to get it dynamically.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay: that code also doesnt give the src file name

Comment: As of now I have done a work around. I search for the folders in Project directory then I match the folder name with regular expression and then take it.

Answer (score 0):

`dateTesting.java` is a Java source file which is not available after compilation to bytecode. The source directory it was in is not available, too.

`dir2` is the `File` of the directory you execute the `.class` file in. It seams that this happens to be `D:\workspace\Project1` but you can't rely on this.

Comment: thanks your reply. my .class file is currently in the following path D:\workspace\Project1\bin so shouldnt the output be as "D:\workspace\Project1\bin"

Answer (score 0):

Your dir2 points to working directory (`new File(".")`). You can't get the location of your sources this way. Your file could sit inside the package (e.g. `your.company.date.dateTesting`). You should just manually concat the "src" to current working directory and then replace file package dots (`.`) with `File.pathSeparator`. In that way you will build the full path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fullFilePath = "H:\\Shared\\Testing\\abcd.bmp";
    File file = new File(fullFilePath);

    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,fullFilePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
    System.out.println(filePath);
```

Output:
H:\Shared\Testing

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to try to read a file from the classpath, then check out this answer:
[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Essentially you can do this

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt");
```

Otherwise, if you have some other requirement, one option is to pass through the src directory as a JVM arg when the application begins and then just read it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** The actual file running */
public static final File    JAR_FILE = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

/** The path to the main folder where the file .jar is run */
public static final String  BASE_DIRECTORY  = (JAR_FILE != null ? JAR_FILE.getAbsolutePath().replace(JAR_FILE.getName(), "") : "notFound");
```

This will work for you both in normal java execution and jar execution. This is the solution I am using in my project.

Comment: thanks for the reply. however this also does not include the source folder name.

Comment: check in different folders, because this should work and work for me, maybe you have some problem in your file position....

Comment: It is named Code Source, but really it is the path for bytecode source, thus, it is in the target folder.